# date & time not loading on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have an html page with a date and time input on it, just straight HTML5

```
<input type="date" id='date' name='date'  style='text-align:center'  required />
```

and

```
<input type='time' id='time' name='time'   style='text-align:center' required />
```

I have the following js code

```
        function gDate(){
    (function () {
        var date = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10),
            field = document.querySelector('#date');
       field.value = date;
 })()
      var time = (new Date()).toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
      document.getElementById('time').value=time;
}
```

I have it setup to run on document.Ready with Jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    gDate();
});
</script>
```

I do have gDate() being loaded from a separate .js page, it works only when I hit refresh.

How can I make it work when the page is loaded.  I have tried

```
<body onLoad="gDate()">
```

but that makes no difference either.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Can you use `console.log()` to see the values?

Comment: works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/sj9vo3zo/

Comment: no error, can't see it in console,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so JQMobile, is the problem.  I removed it from the page in question and the index.html that calls this page, and it does what I want it to do.  That is why I am guessing it would work on jsfiddle.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that jQuery is included, below code snippet works just fine, check developer console in your web browser to check for errors.

```js
function gDate(){
    (function () {
        var date = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10),
            field = document.querySelector('#date');
       field.value = date;
 })()
      var time = (new Date()).toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
      document.getElementById('time').value=time; 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    gDate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id='date' name='date'  style='text-align:center'  required />

<input type='time' id='time' name='time'   style='text-align:center' required />
```

Comment: What is the commotion here? In his question as you can see he is already doing what you are suggesting here. Why these down-voting?

Comment: I have jquery loading, have the script loading, I do have jqmobile loading, could that be a problem?  --- no I commented it out, no change.